# Making UITextField background blink

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

How can I make the background color of a UITextField blink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function that toggles the the background color.

```
-(void) flashBackground
{
  UIColor* color = _flashOn ? [UIColor colorRed] : [UIColor colorWhite];
  _textField.backgroundColor = color;
  [_textField setNeedsDisplay];
  _flashOn = !_flashOn;

}
```

Then setup a timer to call this function

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(flashBackground) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
```

Comment: Thanks.  BTW, it's redColor and whiteColor.  I've extended on this for multiple flashes...with a boolean var on repeats in NSTimer and counter for number of flashes.

Comment: How to I pass a parameter to the @selector method, flashBackground?  For example, passing in a UITextField object.

Comment: You could pass it in the userInfo field, or for more flexibility use the NSInvocation version of scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval.